# C 2d array allocation

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

Can someone help me understand this kind of allocation

im more familiar with something like this:

`result = array = malloc(sizeof(int *) * height);
  for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * width);
  }`

the other allocation is this:

```
  int len;
  len = (*numObjs) * (*numCoords);

  objects = (double **)malloc((*numObjs) * sizeof(double *));

  objects[0] = (double *)malloc(len * sizeof(double));      

  for (i = 1; i < (*numObjs); i++)
    objects[i] = objects[i - 1] + (*numCoords);
```

the values `(*numObjs)` && `(*numCoords)` are taken from a file read which is `100000*20` .

Comment: ah dammit you are right i miss pasted the link , ill change that

Comment: i changed it , as you stated correctly , it's the same as the second allocation of the link http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html , but i really don't get : "You can keep the array's contents contiguous, at the cost of making later reallocation of individual rows more difficult, with a bit of explicit pointer arithmetic"

Comment: Either allocate an array of pointers for a ragged array, or a block width * height * sizeof(element) for a contiguous array. The latter is what you want most often.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean i do understand the result , but i don't understand the whole mechanism behind it , i mean the 1st allocation i wrote is pretty straight forward , but this..

Comment: @frcake Just stick with first allocation. Much more straightforward.

Comment: @RoadRunner i agree, but it's not contiguous :S , i know other contiguous allocation techniques but never seen this one...

Comment: @frcake Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534966/how-to-dynamically-allocate-a-contiguous-block-of-memory-for-a-2d-array)?